# WP7 TimePicker choose time in 24h format

Tags: windows-phone-7, timepicker

Is there a way to get WP7's TimePicker to allow the user to select the time in 24 hour format?  If I set TimePicker.ValueStringFormat to "{0:HH:mm:ss}" it displays in 24h format, but when I click it the input time is still 12h format (with AM/PM).  Can TimePicker be configured to scroll 0-23 instead of 1-12 with AM/PM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7190) you can find a link that can help: however I notice that now the timePicker handle the 12-24 hours conversion authomatically depending on the phone date-time setting!

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities:

- use custom time picker control, eg. [this one](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/phone-elements/controls/wp7-time-picker#Familiar)
- create you own page implementing IDateTimePickerPage interface and point to it in PickerPageUri property of TimePicker control ([more info](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-datepicker-and-timepicker-in-depth--api-and-customization))

I know it should be done easier on standard TimePicker control, but it isn't, so you have to deal with it on your own.

Comment: Thanks, was afraid of that.  Will probably just end up implementing something myself.