# Number picker as same as time picker in alarm app in windows phone 8 (xaml)

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am new on windows phone development and I need scroll number picker (as time picker in Alarm app) as shown in image how can i get it.....

[View Image Here](http://www.imagesup.net/pt-1014143015164.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a list of numbers similar to the TimePicker then populate the same primitive controls that the TimePicker uses.  In this case you're look at `LoopingSelector`, you still need to NuGet/Install the windows phone toolkit.

Use

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    xmlns:toolkit_primitives="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit">


<toolkit_primitives:LoopingSelector>
    <primitives:LoopingSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <!-- design your own square box+text -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </primitives:LoopingSelector.ItemTemplate>      
</toolkit_primitives:LoopingSelector>
```

For more information:

See [TimePickerPage.xaml Source Code](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.WP8/DateTimePickers/TimePickerPage.xaml) 
See [MSDN Forum on LoopingSelector](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-us/27f0f2a4-bafb-42aa-b19a-df030b7c7edc/loopingselector)

---

OLD Solution

If you're using WP 8.0+ SL then see this SO Post: [TimePicker 24h Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335875/wp7-timepicker-choose-time-in-24h-format).  It deals with the Windows Phone Toolkit: TimePicker  `<toolkit:TimePicker>`

---

Else if you're doing a WP8.1 runtime app just set the `ClockIdentifier` to 24HourClock.

```XAML
<TimePicker Header="24HourClock" ClockIdentifier="24HourClock"/>
```

Comment: No i dont need timepicker I need numberpicker or datapicker as same as timepicker.

Comment: See updated solution.  If you want the same list thing, it's call a LoopingSelector.